# Есть ли ресурс для практики на C++?

Tags: c++

Учусь писать на С++, и переодически, пройдя какую-то тему, приходится просто оставлять её в голове без практики. В силу нехватки воображения, наверное.
Так вот вопрос, а есть ли какой то ресурс, [помимо данного сайта] где можно попрактиковаться в той или иной теме. Без проверки, само собой, так просто увидел задачу - сделал.

Ну что-то схожее с *"сборник задач по C++"* или тому подобное. Может даже форум, где просят встроить какие то элементы кода, что-то разобрать или же отредактировать.

Вдруг кто сталкивался.

Comment: https://www.e-olymp.com/uk/, https://acmp.ru/ - Разные задачи. На втором есть даже решения некоторых заданий..

Comment: https://informatics.msk.ru/

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/dashboard

Comment: лет так 35 назад мой учитель попросил 2-х молодых сопляков написать морской бой. Попробуйте игрушку написать. Для себя. А там подтянется

Comment: Согласен с maint. Имхо, самый лучший вариант - писать для себя реальные программы. А то все эти олимпиадные задачи сильно оторваны от реальности, как мне кажется.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Если решать задачи на acmp.ru - от простых к сложным, то вы освоите базовые подходы - циклы, условия, сортировка, рекурсия, работа со строками, алгоритмическая сложность. После этого уже можно браться за написание своего морского боя.

Comment: Всем большое спасибо!
Согласен, свои задачи - это хорошо, несомненно. Но иногда встречаются специфичиские темы, которые в своих проектах ну нафиг не сдались. Вот в этих случаях - хоть задачки порешать)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Project-Based-Tutorials-in-C](https://github.com/rby90/Project-Based-Tutorials-in-C)

[Project-Based-Learning](https://github.com/tuvtran/project-based-learning#cc)

[Build-Your-Own-X](https://github.com/danistefanovic/build-your-own-x)